# maxInvalidPasswordAttempts not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to use account lockouts with a live database. I found a tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.maxinvalidpasswordattempts(v=vs.100).aspx) which says I need to modify the web.config file. I have done as such but the lockout still isn't working. Below is a copy of my web.config file. I've removed the sensitive database information for security purposes. Does it matter that the webapi and the actual login page are in two different projects? I'm using an AJAX call to pass the information to the webapi.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection"
    connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Security;server=;user id=;password=;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings></appSettings>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
        connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
        applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```

**Edit**

As requested below is the login function:

```
login.userLogin = function (username, password) {
jQuery.support.cors = true;
var error = '';
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:60690/token',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        grant_type: 'password'
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $('#divLoginError').addClass('Hidden');
        sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token);
        sessionStorage.setItem('refreshToken', response.refresh_token);
        sessionStorage.setItem('username', response.userName);
        sessionStorage.setItem('expirationDatetime', moment().add(response.expires_in, 'seconds').format());
        window.location = 'index.html';
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        var responseText = jqXHR.responseJSON;
        $('#lblLoginError').text(responseText.error_description);
        $('#divLoginError').removeClass('Hidden');
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Could you show us your page code for the login form also?

Comment: Sure thing. It should be up now.